# Java home error in SparkLaunch

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm running apache spark on hadoop hdfs under CentOS 7, and I've installed everything (including JAVA, Hadoop, Spark) successfully and running spark job with no problem via console. And now I want to invoke spark jobs in java servlet in tomcat, and I use the following code to launch Spark application

```
SparkLauncher spark = new SparkLauncher();
spark.setAppResource("/usr/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop/examples/jars/org.jar");
spark.setMainClass("org.apache.spark.examples.mllib.CommonML");
spark.setMaster("spark://master:7077");
spark.setAppName("CommonDo");
spark.setSparkHome("/usr/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop");
spark.setJavaHome("/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121");
spark.addAppArgs("predict MTHFR677 25.33 69.33 abcdefg");

Process process = spark.launch();
```

And I got the following error description in ErrorStream()

> /usr/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory

As indicated in code, jdk is installed in different directory, which is also configured correctly in /etc/profile, so everything is well if I execute this in console. I don't know why spark trying to find jdk in /usr/lib/jvm/jre, can anyone give me some information? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Add `JAVA_HOME` path variable to the server and give a try. Use the following commands for doing that.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```